# Can we have something akin to Reddit's "Gold" here for nice posts?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounty

Every now and then, you see an *outstanding* answer or question. And you want to give an immediate reward(i.e not a regular bounty, which has a delay before rewarding).

A piece of work that took much  much time to create. You want to give recognition.

Why cannot we give "gold" - which may be a one-time one-way bounty  of 500 points?

It can be restricted such that you cannot endow it , unless and until a post/question has 10 upvotes. And also that such post is still fresh (i.e under 48 hours )

Now I realize that we don't want to copy Reddit, and we aren't. It has the aforementioned constraints - 10 upvote, 48 hours.

Comment: So, some kind of super-upvote? Nah.

Comment: The link for what Martijn referred to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties , also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to pay money to Stack Exchange, and then award 500 reputation to an answer without the reputation being deducted from your own?

Comment: @Coffee I imagine most of them would, actually, as this is going to be contrary to many of the core principles of the company.  They've showed on many occasions that upholding those values is more important to them as a company than selling them out to try to earn some quick cash, at the expense of the integrity of the site.

Comment: @Servy - Granted, this is true and I am definitely not asking anyone to sacrifice these values.  Nowhere in my post did I ask for money being dispensed... Suppose though, that only Reputation is involved? Essentially, it just becomes a more effortless bounty system. In any case, the idea is doomed at -10 votes..

Comment: I saw "reddit" and "feature request" and downvoted...

Comment: @James - haha , this is a reliable metric , reddit sucks ik ,  lol :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We *already have that functionality*.

First click on *Start a bounty*:

> [image: start a bounty]

then pick the last option on the list:

> [image: existing answer option]

Then wait at least 24 hours and award it to the answer you wanted to reward. Waiting longer is an option; the extra attention drawn to the question could lead to extra upvotes for the answer too.

There are no limits on answer score either; you do need to wait for the *question* to be old enough first (posted at least 48 hours ago); the answer can be as fresh as you like.

Comment: I appreciate teh answer, however I was envisioning something more "broad" than bounties, whereby I might also reward a question-asker. But.. What I'm arguing for adds too much gamification and could potentially be abused. so I'll accept this answer , even though I feel it somewhat responds to a different idea

Comment: @Coffee: the question asker already got their reward: answers. The extra attention drawn by a bounty would also lead to upvotes (provided the question is a good one).

Comment: you got me there  :-) back to the drawing  board then :-)