# Can I transfer reputation to answer without using bounty to get more unnecessary attention?

Tags: support, answers, reputation, bounty

I think someone's answer is great and really helped me, and it didn't got enough upvotes because my question didn't got enough attention in the first place. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you upvote it? Or accept it?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yep, but I think it isn't enough. (It just got 1 score) Accepted too.

Comment: Upvoting, accepting, and bounties are the only way you can give an answer rep. So if you have done the other methods, the only one left if "bounty". You can also try to share the link with people, and have _them_ upvote it, but we don't want you doing this often.

Comment: @gunr2171 If I will put bounty it will get unneeded attention, it already solved the question.

Comment: I gave it an upvote because I learned something. That being said, I don't think the user in question is in a dire need of reputation :P

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky, what's wrong with getting more answers? And that attention will draw in more people to read it, which could give more upvotes to the answer you want.

Comment: @Compass Thanks for stalking my user, but like gunr2171 said, it's better not to prefer those methods.

Comment: You can leave a bounty *just to award an answer*. There is an explicit option for that.

Comment: @gunr2171 Bounty is mostly used because question didn't got answer because it didn't got enough attention to get to. (I want to transfer because it didn't got enough attention but I got answer)

Comment: It was answered less than an hour ago. Give it a bit of time to gain upvotes.

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [Can we have something akin to Reddit's "Gold" here for nice posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273005)

Comment: Note that even if you select "reward an existing answer", you'll still need to wait at least 24 hours to award the bounty, during which time the question will be featured.

Comment: I don't understand your concern with the bounty. You said the question didn't get enough attention, but you are worried the bounty will give it attention. If you think the answer really is great then *it deserves the attention*.

Comment: @Tyrsius The thing is the votes it got I don't care much about attention. (Like I said in the other comment, it's a waste of time of other's people to give their attention and try to answer it again or something like that)

Comment: Its often the case that if you put a bounty on the question, it will increase its visibility, which may result in others upvoting the question or answer.  At least if they upvote the answer, it will have your desired effect.

Comment: It is a conspiracy by @LyingOnTheSky to give more rep to the answerer through MEta Effect, instead of offering bounty. Well Played.

Comment: @EatÅPeach I didn't planned it. I didn't put even link here, not sure if they got the right answer -> it wasn't Jon Skeet's, but someone put bounty on it ם.ם. But I noticed that meta effect then I turned down the bounty plan. (Waste of question here)

Comment: It only 'needs' the attention it needs. If other people are interested in the subject, they'll likely find your post; if they think the accepted answer is great, they'll likely upvote it. Allow the site to work on its own, instead of trying to game it when you 'don't think it's enough'. Rule of thumb: ask yourself 'what if everyone on the site did what I am suggesting? Would the site gain value or lose value?'

Comment: Well, now that you've got your answer, why don't you try to give me er, 500 reps? :-)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As gunr2171 points out in his [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276632/can-i-transfer-reputation-to-answer-without-using-bounty#comment116547_276632) the only ways to reward an answer are upvoting, accepting and awarding a bounty.

It's perfectly acceptable to start a bounty to reward an existing answer - one of the bounty reasons is just that:

> **Reward existing answer**
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

You don't have to wait for the bounty to expire before awarding it:

> A bounty can be awarded 24 hours after the bounty was started. Any answer to the question, even an existing answer that has already been awarded one or more bounties, is eligible to be manually awarded the bounty.
>
> To award the bounty manually, click on the <kbd>+50</kbd> (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) button on the left side of the answer you want to award:
>
> [image: Screenshot]

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/59303)

Comment: I'm gunr2171 and I approve this answer.

Comment: One last question, it will instantly awarded to the answer and won't cause unneeded attention? (It will take people's time for nothing if not) Or it will be normal one for a week.

Comment: Never mind, looks like Martijn Pieters answered that question. (Don't remember why I ignored it)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky - why are you so worked up about the idea of "unneeded attention"? Even if your question has already been answered, what you're trying to do is reward what you see as a good and helpful answer, so is it so bad if more people potentially see that helpful answer?

Comment: @sphanley They can answer other's questions instead, answering my question one more time won't help, and will waste time. It's helpful if they need it, then if they need it -> they will search for it. I think I can agree that I am too much concerned about it.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky. You think the answer is good, right? So it's a good thing if people see it. It might teach them something useful. They might upvote it too. I don't see a downside here.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky Why do you think that more views implies means more answers? If the answer is so good that it requires a bounty is (generally) either because it is correct and very complete (and thus new answers would just be "duplicates") or because it shows some peculiarity about the problem that you didn't consider but that it's interesting/useful. In the latter case either you need a "standard answer" and thus new answers are welcome, or something like that was already provided and thus new answers are likely to be "duplicates". Duplicated answers get downvotes, so people don't post them.

Comment: @TRiG I am agreeing with you, I was a bit obssessed over keeping my low-attention, while I got votes on my question too because of the meta-effect.

Comment: @Bakuriu I think the whole wrong with what I thought is because my lack of research about bounties. I thought it was only for getting better answers or attention (For answers), I was completely wrong. I thought too that it will attract more answers. I didn't said anything about duplicates, but about attempts to give better answer -> because I thought bounties are all about better answers.