# Feature Request: Award your own reputation to authors of great questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, bounty

The general low quality of questions is a problem. Allowing users to award their own reputation to authors of great *questions* would help.

I can currently award reputation (via bounty) only to authors of great *answers*. From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/246570):

> You can award your bounty to any answer on the question. This makes it possible for users to reward particularly good answers with more rep than a standard upvote would provide.
>
> To indicate that your bounty will be awarded to an existing answer, choose "Reward existing answer" when asked "Why are you starting this bounty?"

I recently came across [this well-written question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29349993/1445366). I upvoted it, but I'd like to similarly reward the author with "more rep than a standard upvote would provide".

Broader than the scope of this individual question, this ability could help encourage users to write better questions. A surprise award could also help Stack Overflow feel more welcoming and less intimidating for new users.

---

#### Additional Details

- This should not be named *Bounty*. I'd call it *reward*, or perhaps *good question reward*.
- Like bounties, a minimum reputation level should be necessary to judge good questions. While awarding bounties only [requires a rep of 75](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), I'd propose a minimum rep of 1,000 to reward good questions. This would help address Servo's concern in the comments that this would encourage poor, click-baity questions.
- Like bounties, the author would lose any reputation they reward.

---

#### Related but not duplicate

My [search for existing questions on this topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+bounty) revealed only one similar question, which is a different proposal. [Can we have something akin to Reddit's “Gold” here for nice posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273005/1445366) suggests a 500-point bounty for question authors when the post has 10+ upvotes. I'm suggesting an arbitrary bounty that any well-qualified user can give to any question author.

One comment in that post is related:

> The question asker already got their reward: answers. The extra attention drawn by a bounty would also lead to upvotes (provided the question is a good one).

That said, these indirect rewards aren't directly tied to *writing a great question* and do not directly encourage this behavior.

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about an exact concept (and proper naming) for a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: You're incorrectly conflating popular with quality.  There are tons of questions with lots of upvotes that are just bikeshed questions that don't even belong on the site.  A significant bounty like this would only encourage people to post more inappropriate but popular and click-baity posts that people love talking about but that are rarely even on topic questions.  The best questions come from people with actual problems, actually trying to get help; not from people asking questions to try to get rep, without caring about the answers.

Comment: @Servy Good point. I was also already thinking about asking the OP for the certain conditions and judgments necessary to make such _award_.

Comment: @Servy Why do you think high-rep users would reward those click-bait posts? My point is that we should be doing a better job of awarding actual good questions, like the one I linked to. Don't you think high-rep users know better?

Comment: @AaronBrager I'd expect to see at least some amount of it for exactly the same reason questions like those get upvotes.  People are entertained by them, regardless of their value.

Comment: @Servy That could be mostly addressed by making this a privilege with a minimum bounty. I have updated this post to suggest a 1,000 rep requirement to earn this privilege.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Outside of making this an earned privilege, do you suggest any additional conditions / judgments necessary?

Comment: Questions are generally second-class citizens on Stack Overflow, and the general assumption is that *getting an answer* is the true reward for a good question. The reasoning in this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/ explains the thinking behind it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, I've read that, and agree with it, but that doesn't mean we don't need to improve question optimization. On the other hand, we clearly do: there are many more poor questions than good ones, and the close queue shows no signs of getting to zero any time soon.

Comment: I changed the question title because it was misleading and may have been the reason for the downvotes. It sounded like you just wanted to give more reputation to people which isn't really what StackExchange is about. I do think giving some of your own reputation might not be that bad of an idea.

Comment: @aug Thanks for the edit. I think it clarifies things.

Comment: @AaronBrager And you think that the ability to award bounties to questions would decrease the number of low quality questions the site gets?  I strongly doubt it.  The vast majority of the people that ask the worse of the low quality questions wouldn't ever spend enough time looking at how the site works to even know that such a feature would be possible, let alone care enough about Imaginary Internet Points to spend time crafting a quality question just to get some.

Comment: arrgh you've entirely changed the proposal and now comments and answers don't stand. Answers were based on you proposing to use the current "bounty" system. Not a *entirely new* "reward" system.

Comment: @James I don't think I changed anything except the name. See [the revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/289001/revisions).

Comment: The bit under "Additional Details" section proposes a "new" reward system. Your original question seemingly  proposed using the current bounty system, as per the answers. nw

Comment: I think the key thing lacking, per Pekka's answer, is that there is no immediately obvious way to advertise rewards for specific criteria in advance, the way bounties advertise existing questions that are specific criteria for answers. So first, propose a "request for questions"-style feature that can work analogously, and then this can be part of it, or perhaps even the only way to post an RfQ. As a simple post-hoc "here have a surprise reward" it fills almost exactly the same conceptual niche as voting, unlike bounties, so doesn't really work as posted.

Comment: Related question on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135469/271946

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this sounds kind, and potentially great on face value, I'm not in favour of it.

The biggest issue I see is:

### Rep going to the wrong place

The questioner doesn't need bounty rep as they have a question to ask and want an answer, not rep. 
A question "already exists" as the questioner has a question to ask, so their "*payment*" in the Q&A transaction is an answer, which is what they wanted.

However answers do not "already exist", it takes someone time to answer, and their only "*payment*" in the transaction is gaining rep (of course the joy of helping someone, etc).

So questioner gets their answer, answerer gets their rep.
And I don't think questioner should get bounty rep as well as an answer, not when that rep could have been given to a deserving answerer who *only* gets rep.

A great question which would arguably deserve bounty rep would *usually* also get a great answer, and the rep should go to the answerer.

### Doesn't attract better questions

The question has to *already exist* to be able to apply a bounty. So this proposal wouldn't attract better questions, as the current bounty does with answers.

The new feature *might* make *some* questioners ask better questions, but:

1. Poor questioners tend not to care about such things, just getting their
   answer
2. Anyone asking a question worthy of bounty rep is likely going to be
   asking a decent one anyway regardless of this feature
3. Hardly anyone will award their rep to a question, so once people
   realise this there will be no attraction to spend time writing a
   better question

### Only awards a few

There are not many "great" questions, certainly not new ones, and the older ones have probs got enough rep by now from years of the odd vote here and there.

So as not many people will award a question bounty rep, and *great* questions are rare, we'd be introducing a new reward system for a limited few people who write great questions, which is not really fair on a large community driven site.

Comment: I disagree with your point #3, but your counterarguments #1 and #2 make sense.

Comment: @AaronBrager You really think people will award rep to questions? They barely get *upvotes* which cost *nothing*, let alone something which actually costs at least 50 rep.

Comment: I think high-rep users will.

Comment: I disagree strongly. I think high rep users will award answers over questions. Even if so, there aren't many great questions worthy of such a reward

Comment: I agree about the lack of great questions. My hypothesis is that their quantity will increase with the availability of additional rewards. There are plenty of high-rep users who already give away lots of rep to great answers, and would also give rep to reward great questions. Once you hit 20k, there are no additional privileges to earn by going higher. I don't really have anything to lose by spending lots of rep rewarding great content.

Comment: You cannot force or attract **great** questions with a reward system, as anyone with such a question will post it anyway. Maybe that's wrong, but it's how I see it. You could offer £500 real life cash, and you'd  not attract many more **great** questions. they don't exist in the quantity you seem to believe they do

Comment: Perhaps we have a definitional issue. I don't mean to reward questions that are revolutionary within computer programming, but simply questions that embody the ideas outlined in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Almost all of the poor questions on Stack Overflow could be greatly improved by following these guidelines.

Comment: I'd say there are thousands and thousands of poor questions which could become great questions through better writing.

Comment: "*I'd say there are thousands and thousands of poor questions which could become great questions through better writing*" Well yes that is the basic premise. But how would bounty or new reward system bring about such a change? Do you have any example questions you would award such a reward to? And how much rep would you award to the example?

Comment: Yes, I linked to [this example question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29349993/1445366) in my post. I would offer 300-500 rep. The availability of such rewards would encourage users to spend more time writing and editing their questions.

Comment: Can you make a compelling argument as to why you would award that 500 of your rep? It's gained 2 upvotes - if that is unfair or wrong, then the issue we need to tackle is getting people to vote more, not just throwing a heap of rep at it.

Comment: @AaronBrager "questions that embody the ideas outlined in [...]" - you want to give bonus reputation to people who follow the _minimum requirements_ for questions? The posts you linked are more a list of things to avoid to not create a crappy question; every question that does _not_ adhere to these standards should be downvoted and possibly closed. I don't know why you seem to think it would be a good idea to award 500 rep to a guy who only ever posted 3 questions and 1 answer, just because he _followed the rules_. That's no way to solve the SO quality problems.

Comment: Many systems encourage behavior by rewarding people who follow the rules. And as I point out earlier, the current system isn't working well.

Comment: @AaronBrager The current system isn't working well because the quality standards are not enforced enough. Most people who post a crappy question or simply copypaste their homework assignments on SO don't care about creating a high-quality resource or even about rep, they simply want someone to do their work. And btw, people _are_ getting rewarded for following the rules, by _getting good answers_ and upvotes. But as you seriously want to give somebody the equivalent rep of 50 answer upvotes for nothing more than creating a MCVE, I don't think this discussion will lead anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. You changed my mind on this.

Answer (score -2):

It's a nice thought but it wouldn't work.

Bounties are not suited to encourage good questions.

They work fine in the current system where only answers can get bounties: there is a question that really really needs an answer, so bad that someone (either the asker or someone else) is willing to *lose some reputation points* to see the question receive a good answer.

When that happens and someone puts the rep on the table, a competition starts, with the bounty being an extra incentive to provide a really great answer. If all goes well, a lot of people think or Google really hard, good answers come up, the bounty is awarded, and a good time was had by all.

With *questions*, you could only give the reward after the great question *has already been asked.* There is no competition to be had, it'd be like tipping someone for providing exceptional service. That would be nice occasionally, but because only a tiny fraction of people will be willing to part with points to reward a great question they come across, the overall cultural effect of this will be about zero.

- You can already start a bounty on someone else's question. If you see a great question that still lacks an answer, you are always welcome to do *that*.
- If you want a *reliable* mechanism to encourage good questions, it already exists in the form of voting! If you want to encourage *more* good questions, you would have to, for example, roll back the change that reduced the rep gained on a question upvote from 10 to 5. [It seems unlikely that will happen, though.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: "it'd be like tipping someone for providing exceptional service": why do you think "only a tiny fraction of people will be willing to part with points"? Plenty of people tip… and with money, which is more valuable than rep.

Comment: @AaronBrager: Probably mostly because it isn't really a service *for me*, but them doing what's in their best interest to get an answer. Regarding rep for question upvotes: I'm not sure there's any connection at all, though I don't have any data...

Comment: Also: re "it already exists in the form of voting", this system doesn't appear to be working well.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is a good idea.  Look, the point, other than egoboo, of SO is to create a useful resource. Certainly my students at the various places I've taught, think so.

It's hard to make it a good resource without encouraging good questions. While upvote points are good, bounty points would be a much more significant sort of approval.

Comment: But naming it _bounty_ is misleading. It should be something like a _"bonus"_ that a user can award from their own rep to the OP.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'd be fine changing the name of the reward.

Comment: @AaronBrager Yeah _reward_, that's much better.

Comment: I updated the post to distinguish between *bounty* and *reward*.