# Badge or bounty to encourage questions and answers with good quality (pass an exam)

Tags: feature-request, bounty, question-quality, quality-improvement, answer-quality

Is it possible to consider a mandatory badge/bounty for newly joined contributors? The badge/bounty is earned by taking a training and passing an exam; a new contributor can post questions or answers only after achieving this badge. When the new contributor publishes a question/answer, it triggers the training if they hadn't earned the badge/bounty already.

**This proposal differs from the question: [Stack Overflow needs an entrance exam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406703/stack-overflow-needs-an-entrance-exam) because it suggests a specific badge or bounty instead of an entrance exam. This new approach is part of the existing mechanism to earn a reputation in the community**. It is similar in the sense it requires to pass an exam, but **presented as a reward instead of an entry barrier**. Some time similar ideas are  rejected just in the way they are presented.

There are concerns about the decreasing quality of questions. Here is a good example: [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow). It takes a tremendous effort in the Review Queues to ensure minimum quality standards. Expecting people, on their own, to self-train or get information on how to post questions or answers doesn't seem to work.

A group of reputed people from the community can create this training material, and the corresponding exam. It's worth more than spending so much time on question triage, answer review, etc. I think it may help.

Comment: I like the idea but a few months after it fully launches all the answers to all the questions will be easily be searchable. So people that dont want to do this will just search the answers and this wont do anything. Thought it may help a few people

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to the proposed staging area?

Comment: @snakecharmerb No. The staging area requires far more active workpower than the company is anticipating. Curating a selection of answers and introduction material is done once, and then maintained with minimal effort and an enormous contributor to impacted user ratio. It's a _related_ proposal, but not equivalent. It's also possible to do both (at least in an optimal world; first questions with extra steps is set up for failure already)

Comment: That said, this idea has been proposed before somewhere, and I'm personally a fan of some variation of it. @Ethan's concern is still correct; answers to anything like this will eventually be made public, and that's why it's a tricky system to build. Automatic onboarding systems still need a massive upgrade. The tour is nowhere near good enough for the average user

Comment: @snakecharmerb Like Zoe said that they are not the same but are similar. They could work together to help athe"bad" posts made. Thought that is only true if this works as intended and people don't cheat.

Comment: However, a trick to a proper quiz-like system is retention rate; i.e. how many people can you keep away from search engines? This isn't possible to predict, largely because it changes over time depending on how "bad" the questions are. The question wizard is a step towards fully automated onboarding, but it still remains incredibly weak alone. But onboarding in general is a topic discussed probably hundreds of times by now, and we've seen near 0 overall progress. I fear that any attempts to provide good alternatives is a waste of time, no matter how good the proposal or discussions are

Comment: The point on retention rates (I massively digressed from the main point) is that, for instance, 50% not googling is still 50% we might be able to educate to use the site better. Even 20-30% is still a sizable dent in the volume we're dealing with. But again, impossible to predict in advance, and impossible to predict whether it'll remain along that trend or not. And because the company is too busy with other useless stuff, we'll never even have the chance to see any data related to whether this is feasible or not

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine it sounds similar a year ago and still we are facing the same problem. My approach is rebranded a little bit different, instead of an entry exam, to put in a positive way to earn a badge/bounty it is sensitive topic as I see from some of the answer on the post you shared, so it requires to express it in a positive way.

Comment: thanks @chivracq for your input I made some corrections and passed it to Grammarly. English is my second language.

Comment: Even with an excellent proposal and meta backing, it will probably never happen. It would require another company or entity. [A comment to the duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406703/stack-overflow-needs-an-entrance-exam#comment886701_406703) expressed it well: *"Your suggestion is LIKELY in direct conflict with the company's goals. Do not forget SO is not a charity. It is a company whose main goal is to be profitable. If you limit the number of users, you are lowering the company's profits."*

Comment: To solve the search engine problem, there could be a *filtered* version of Stack Overflow (like [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_content)), `bestofstackoverflow.com`, manually and/or automatically filtered (and even mashed up content where posts are merged and partly rewritten). And even subsets of that, `python.bestofstackoverflow.com`, `java.bestofstackoverflow.com`,   In fact, given the [CC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license) license, anyone is free to do that!

Comment: @PeterMortensen how your comment about engine problem relates to my suggestion? Thanks for any clarification

Comment: Even if you disguise it as a reward an exam is still an exam, why don't you add your suggestions to the linked duplicate? There's already quite a lot of discussion on that post.

Comment: @David Leal: The decreasing quality of questions (and the duplication) very much affect engine results. Search engines now seem to be prefer *newer*, *short* (too short), low-scored, low-quality questions (most often without any indication of what the canonical question is) with few and noncomprehensive low-quality answers. Those that pass your entrance exam (have the badge) could get a higher chance of getting their questions included in the filtered version.

Comment: On another note: Positive reinforcement is different from a requirement — *"a new contributor can post questions or answers* ***only*** *after achieving this badge"* (my emphasis). The presentation is important, but it is still en entry barrier.

Comment: There is also the problem of cheating. Someone will post the answers to the quiz on the Internet (and *all* of them if questions are selected from a larger set of questions, say 20 questions out of a pool of 792 questions).

Comment: @PeterMortensen cheating is possible on everywhere, but still we have certification exams on other matters. As part of the Reviews Queues we can have an activity for increasing the database of the exam questions and reviewing them. This will reduce the chance of cheating. AWS community (from AWS) actually asks certified team members to get involved on providing exam questions for their certifications.

Comment: up next: SO Certifications! 800% more meaningless than w3schools certs!!

Comment: No amount of testing people on fake questions will ensure the questions that are asked are *actually useful*. Even users who've been here for 13 years, answered thousands of questions, or even asked thousands of questions, can't accurately predict which questions will end up useful.

Comment: @PeterMortensen true about entry barrier, but it depends on your marketing strategy and on how you sell it. When Apple releases a new iPhone there is an entry barrier for buying the first ones in the Apple Store, but they sell it as something appealing to get the first iPhones (the first badge in SO for example) not as a stock limitation. I am not saying we need to do the same, just to take into account how to brand it properly

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252829/1595451

Comment: @Rubén interesting 8 years ago was proposed this idea and still dealing with question/answers with low quality.

Comment: The whole idea of SO moderation being done by community members is to deal with  posts from anyone... if you will be counting how long we have dealing with low quality posts what about counting from the creation date of [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1) -> Jul 31, 2008 at 21:26 ( deleted 11 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

Nah, we just need to downvote and report more and trust the system (software and community).

---

After reading the contributions to this and other questions, new and old, my current thinking is that the system  already has several things intended to help askers to make good questions but terrible askers just ignore them, so it's very likely that they will ignore any badge / reputation bounty.

The terrible posts eventually will be deleted, many terrible askers will never come back and if they persist doing terrible posts, eventually will be banned... if community members who cares about the SO content quality vote and report.

Answer (score -1):

I think that there are some work to do to make this idea a good feature request. Please checkout [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/1595451), [Introducing the Staging Ground, an attempt at improving the first-time asker experience - What was asking your first question like?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416428/1595451) and [staging-ground](/questions/tagged/staging-ground). In the meantime, following there are some thoughts around some of pieces of this feature request (hopefully they might help to improve the this feature request or to create a new one around the overall idea)

I understand that this feature request mentions an exam not as a discrimination tool but as personal development tool as the idea is not about using the exam as an entry barrier but as formative exam to improve the skills and knowledge required to make a good question.

There is already a posting question rate limit (see [Questions are now rate-limited to 1 per 90 minutes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256323/1595451)). The formative exam could be presented as something to do in the meantime the user gets some feedback or the post rate block is lifted.

Users that repeatedly fail in making "good" posts will get a temporary posting ban ( see [Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/1595451)). The interest on lifting the post ban might be a better motivation to improve their posts than a badge / bounty for many.

SO is currently developing the "Staging Ground" that is pointed too to change the new user experience. IMHO, the feature request should mention who the *exam-badge-bounty* relates to it.

AFAIK there is only one SO badge that could be earned by doing something different than participating directly on the main site / meta, the [not a robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge, and there is no way to be rewarded for doing other thing than posting answer with a bounty. If we consider the referred badge as the exception that makes the rule, then the most probable answer that this type of proposals could get is no, but it doesn't make any hurt to explore the ideas.

Something to be developed in this or a related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is the proposal of the place to host the training material. One place might be Meta (we already have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) for posts about using SO, like [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/1595451)). Besides questions and answers we have the [tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki)s and [articles](/questions/tagged/articles). It could be nice if some tags and articles could have a badge like the [informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge that is earned by reading the tour.

[tag-wiki](/questions/tagged/tag-wiki) are supposed to summarize the topic and provide tag usage guidance. They sometimes includes recommendations about how to ask a question about the topic and point to learning materials.

Nowadays on the public site, [articles](/questions/tagged/articles) are available only for collectives. I think that it is possible to write articles about the pretty basics of the topics related to the collective and that include tips about how to ask good questions about around the article content and point users to external resources that already  have in place some sort of rewards like [open badges](https://openbadges.org/).

I'm wondering if there is already a third party giving rewards to encourage "newbies" to make quality posts on SO.

I think that it's too early to consider to add an additional type of community created SO content, i.e. some sort of call to action to promote better contributions.

Regarding bounties, nowadays the bounty system rewards reputation points to answers. Here are couple of [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)'s about rewarding questions instead of answers

- [Feature Request: Award your own reputation to authors of great questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289001/1595451)
- [Award a bounty for a good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319862/1595451)

Regarding encouraging good quality answers by offering a bounty coming from community members, please feel free to be generous and offer bounties for this purpose following the current guidelines -> [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/289691)

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what this answer has to do with this feature request. You say that the feature request needs more work and then go off on a tangent about other features / feature requests.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for you feedback. I edit the answer... hoping that it's a bit better now.

Comment: That does help. Although note that the OP still expects this to be an entry barrier as they mention in the question: "_a new contributor can post questions or answers only after achieving this badge_" so this is still effectively an entrance exam.

Comment: But immediately after the OP says "When the new contributor publishes a question/answer, it triggers the training if they hadn't earned the badge/bounty already"

Comment: And how does that change things? That would be expected behaviour if such an entrance exam were to be implemented...

Comment: If users can posts without having passed the exam, then the exam it's not an entry barrier

Comment: **If** they can post. Redirecting the user to the exam if they haven't completed it does stop them from posting.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback but I think that it's too centered on the OP's words rather than mine. Please post your criticism to the OP 's words as comments to the question or as a new answer. If your point is that you don't like exams, I get it.

Comment: This is related to the OPs words since this is an answer on their feature request, it seems you have a different interpretation of it from what the OP meant. I feel this can be a separate post / feature request of its own.

Comment: I don't think that this could be a separate post, but eventually it might be the source of a new feature request... perhaps I will post it by myself, I haven't decided that yet.

Comment: This is one of my first posts in META, @Rubén most of the links your shared are very old, which tells me it is an **old problem, with no solution yet**. Which make me think the problem is not incomplete or bad formulated proposals, but lack of action by SO about this problem. Relying on huge manual intervention by the community nowadays without using the technology in our favor to minimize this effort is not fair. We should focus on answering questions rather than the current triage effort dealing with low quality questions. The badge idea, is to use a positive reward instead of punishment.

Comment: There are recent posts even from moderators complaining about lack of action of the company, so that isn't some to discuss here. If you are looking for that this feature request get the attention of SO, I think that it fair to suggest you to follow the feature request guidelines. Anyway, if you want to prefer using your time answering questions instead of reviewing, please feel free to do it.